# Google maps markers event listener click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an issue with google maps marker. Actually on my map I added several markers with an event listener to trigger an event on click, but they all seam to trigger the same function.

```
for(var j = 0; j < lat_long.length; j ++) {
markers[j] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latitudeAndLongitudeOne,
    icon: self.icon,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
    map: self.map,
    title: lat_long[i].name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(markers[j], 'click', function() {
    alert(j);
});
```

}

I have  **alert( x )** , with  x being the id of the last item inserted. whatever the marker I click on.

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var markers= [];
for(var i = 0; i < lat_long.length; i ++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latitudeAndLongitudeOne,
        icon: self.icon,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
        map: self.map,
        title: lat_long[i].name
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        alert(marker.title);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

I am not sure but you can try

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can´t define the markers as you do. Create an global array and push in that array the instances of each created marker.

So:
For all markers, define an array to keep the reference of each created marker:

```
var markers = []; //Global Marker Array
function printMarker(lat, lng){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Now you just have to add the clickListener to the current reference of the marker witin you loop.

Comment: Excuse me I just wrote a part of the whole code, as you can see I use an array, the declaration is not in the part I wrote, The fact Is I have markers on the map. Having markers on map is not the issue! The issue is to be able to click and trigger the "right" code.

Comment: Don't know if I made myself clear enougth, excuse my poor english